# Coloring minimum bars in seaborn FacetGrid barplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

Any easy way to automatically color (or mark in any way) the minimum/maximum bars for each plot of a FacetGrid?

For example, how to mark the minimal Z value on each one of the following 16 plots?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10, 20, 30, 40]*4, 'Y':[1,2,3,4]*4, 'W':range(16), 'Z':range(16)})
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="A", col="Y", sharey=False)
g.map(sns.barplot, "W", "Z")
plt.show()
```

Comment: DataFrame is a bit "weird", generated for the sake of example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach loops through the diagonal axes, for each ax searches the minimum height of the bars and then colors those:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 20, 30, 40] * 4, 'Y': [1, 2, 3, 4] * 4, 'W': range(16), 'Z': range(16)})
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="A", col="Y", sharey=False)
g.map(sns.barplot, "W", "Z")

for i in range(len(g.axes)):
    ax = g.axes[i, i]
    min_height = min([p.get_height() for p in ax.patches])
    for p in ax.patches:
        if p.get_height() == min_height:
            p.set_color('red')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: That works. However, I modified it to work on all plots (and not only on diagonals).